How do I keep scripts between renderings in Blazor .Net8?
I'm using blazor .net 8 with global interactive auto and I've put my scripts in App.razor, but they only load in prerender, when the application render interactive mode the scripts stop working and do the "flick" because the page is render for the second time.
How do I persist the Javascripts between renders (prerender to Interactive Auto for example)?
I've read a few things and discover the "data-permanent"
<div data-permanent> 

but doesn't work.
Is there any way to persist Javascripts scripts between renders?

I believe you have a misconception there how scripts work in App.razor: They stay present at all times, however they are only executed upon initial page load. You may want to look into using JSRuntime to call your JS method once the component has finished rendering maybe?

I don't know, I tried removing the scripts from App.razor and placing them in my component with these lines (for example) `
`. This way, my script that changes a table (for example) when the page is initialised continues to do its job
but when the rendering changes, there's a kind of flicker on my page. I didn't want to disable prerender, is there any solution for this flicker not to happen?

You can try passing in an identifier to cache the state during prerendering and to retrieve the state after prerendering. For details, please refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-8.0#stateful-reconnection-after-prerendering

I'll try that, I searched and found  too, maybe it will work, maybe not.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/static-server-rendering?view=aspnetcore-8.0
